# Table is not displaying cell arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell

I had a question because I was doing the tutorial on http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html and their table displayed everything in columns, but mine just stayed as cell arrays. How do I display them like in the tutorial?

I get this:

```
      X                Y             YPrime        YDiffierence 
_____________    _____________    _____________    _____________

[1x10 double]    [1x10 double]    [1x10 double]    [1x10 double]
```

I want something like this:

```
 X        Y          Fit         FitError  
    ___    _______    __________    ___________
  0          0    0.00044117    -0.00044117
0.1    0.11246       0.11185     0.00060836
0.2     0.2227       0.22231     0.00039189
0.3    0.32863       0.32872    -9.7429e-05
0.4    0.42839        0.4288    -0.00040661
0.5     0.5205       0.52093    -0.00042568
0.6    0.60386       0.60408    -0.00022824
0.7     0.6778       0.67775     4.6383e-05
0.8     0.7421       0.74183     0.00026992
0.9    0.79691       0.79654     0.00036515
  1     0.8427       0.84238      0.0003164
1.1    0.88021       0.88005     0.00015948
1.2    0.91031       0.91035    -3.9919e-05
1.3    0.93401       0.93422      -0.000211
1.4    0.95229       0.95258    -0.00029933
1.5    0.96611       0.96639    -0.00028097
1.6    0.97635       0.97652    -0.00016704
1.7    0.98379       0.98379     8.3306e-07
1.8    0.98909       0.98893     0.00016278
1.9    0.99279       0.99253     0.00025791
  2    0.99532       0.99508     0.00024347
2.1    0.99702       0.99691      0.0001131
2.2    0.99814       0.99823    -8.8548e-05
2.3    0.99886       0.99911    -0.00025673
2.4    0.99931       0.99954    -0.00022451
2.5    0.99959       0.99936     0.00023151
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating your table, you have to be careful of the dimensions of the input data. Your input data is `1 x 10` (a row vector) rather than `10 x 1` (a column vector). The second is what is needed in order to properly populate multiple rows of a table.

```
t = table(rand(1, 10), rand(1, 10), rand(1, 10), rand(1, 10))

%//     Var1             Var2             Var3             Var4
%// _____________    _____________    _____________    _____________
%//
%// [1x10 double]    [1x10 double]    [1x10 double]    [1x10 double]
```

Versus

```
%// Note the order of the inputs to rand
t = table(rand(10, 1), rand(10, 1), rand(10, 1), rand(10, 1))

%//   Var1         Var2       Var3        Var4
%// _________    ________    _______    ________
%// 
%//   0.34446     0.46092    0.34112    0.091113
%//   0.78052     0.77016    0.60739     0.57621
%//   0.67533     0.32247    0.19175     0.68336
%// 0.0067153     0.78474    0.73843     0.54659
%//   0.60217     0.47136    0.24285     0.42573
%//   0.38677    0.035763    0.91742     0.64444
%//   0.91599     0.17587    0.26906     0.64762
%// 0.0011511     0.72176     0.7655     0.67902
%//   0.46245     0.47349    0.18866     0.63579
%//   0.42435     0.15272     0.2875     0.94517
```

With the specific example that you have shown, I'm guessing you didn't take the transpose of `x` when you created it in the following line:

```
x = (0:0.1:2.5)';
```

This would have caused all of your data to be row vectors rather than column vectors (leading to the issue above). You could either update `x` (Adding the transpose) and re-run everything or you could just alter the `table` command to take the transpose of all values.

```
T = table(x.', y.', f.', (y-f).', 'VariableNames', {'X','Y','Fit','FitError'})
```